# Getting values by pointer

Tags: go

How I can get a value by key through a pointer?

```
m := map[interface{}]interface{}{    
        "uid": "007",            
        "msg": "Hi James!",             
}                                  

fmt.Println(m["msg"]) //Ok!

p := &m

fmt.Println(p["msg"]) //??
```

play with: http://play.golang.org/p/4LOBrog93t

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just through the value of the pointer:

```
fmt.Println((*p)["msg"])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Also I've confused about this scenario: http://play.golang.org/p/m6uT3r1bA2 Can you help me again?

Comment: Oh, solved, need 
`fmt.Printf("%#v \n", (*p.(*map[interface{}]interface{})))`